# Use cookie across whole website

Tags: javascript, cookies

I've painted myself into a corner. I've set up a cookie to recognise if a dialog box has been minimized and if so when the page is revisited then keep the box minimized.

This works great on the page that you minimize the box on, however I would like to have this cookie work across the site. If you mimimize the dialog box on one page I would like it to be minimized across all pages. Here is what I have so far:

```
$('.ui-dialog-titlebar-minimize').click(function() {

  $.cookie('message', 'minimized', {
    expires: 7 
    +'; domain=http://mysite.co.uk'
  });

return false;
})

if($.cookie('message') === 'minimized') { 

$("#membership")    .dialogExtend("minimize");
}
```

Comment: dup? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5977813/jquery-cookie-domain-causing-cookie-not-to-set

Comment: No because they are trying to set the domain to be different from the site they are on. I want to use the domain of the site I am on.

Comment: did you try to remove domain and check what is it set?

Comment: Yes, it sets the cookie to the exact page I am on. i.e. /mywebsite/events/nameofevent/ when I navigate to another event page the cookie is unset.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, found a solution. The problem was with the path setting. The path should point to the root.

```
'path':'/'



jQuery(function ($) {

$('.ui-dialog-titlebar-minimize').click(function() {

  $.cookie('message', 'minimized', {
    expires: 7,
    'path':'/'
  });

return false;
})

if($.cookie('message') === 'minimized') { 

$("#membership")    .dialogExtend("minimize");
}
});
```

Found the solution here:

[My cookies are only available on PHP pages they are set on, is this normal?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9679313/my-cookies-are-only-available-on-php-pages-they-are-set-on-is-this-normal?rq=1)